# How to get current item position of recyclerview while scrolling a NestedScrollView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

**I have recycler view in nestedScrollView  android , how to get current item position of recyclerview while scrolling nestedScrollView**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/constraintMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
       <Linearlayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
           <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_all"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        </Linearlayout>

  </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

> there **addOnScrollListener** and **setOnScrollListener** funcions are
>   not calling with recyclerview

Answer (score -1):

you can find first visible item of recycler view from layout manager.

```
LinearLayoutManager myLayoutManager = myRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();
int scrollPosition = myLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
```

Others are

```
findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
```

use as per your need.

Comment: its always returning  0

Comment: What do you mean by current item? Item that you select on click or top visible item in list?

If you want top visible item then above code will work fine for you.

if you want to get item that you select from list. for this, you have to listen a click event for each item in your recycler view adapter.

Comment: i just use this code in onScrollChange for nestedscrollview but also its stell showing scrollPosition  is 0

Comment: Just let me know, what do you mean by current position? is it at top OR clicked item?